# Is it allowed to write if-statements as one-liner?

Tags: python, pep

What is the recommended way to write if-statements regarding newlines?

There are obviously two possibilities. The first is from [Google's Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Statements#Statements), the second is the variant with a new line.

```py
if foo: bar(foo)
```

versus

```py
if foo:
    bar(foo)
```

Which variant should be preferred **with regard to existing guidelines or [PEPs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) (to avoid opinion-based discussions)**?

Comment: "Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged." — [PEP 8#other recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

Comment: line-by-line code is easier to read

Comment: For future reference, if you have a question about recommended Python style, check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) first.

Comment: There is a slight speed difference, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290824/are-compound-if-statements-faster-or-multiple-if-statements

Comment: @CodeCupboard That question is comparing something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations):

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.
>
> [...]
>
> Rather not:
>
> `if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()`
>
> `do_one(); do_two(); do_three()`